# How to apply k-means clustering to dataframe with mixed data?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

i have a dataframe with mixed data. The data includes different categories, like location, employee ID, job code, and some other values. I converted to indicator variables:

`data_norm = pd.get_dummies(data)`
then, my dataset looks like 4414 rows × 12995 columns
then tried using a basic implementation of k-means:

```
kmeans = KMeans(6)
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(data_norm_df)
labels = pd.DataFrame(clusters)
labeleddata = pd.concat((data,labels),axis=1)
labeleddata = labeleddata.rename({0:'labels'},axis=1)
```

but get this error: `ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=6.`

i also tried this:

```
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
k_means.fit(data_norm_df)
clusters = k_means.fit_predict(data_norm_df)
labels = pd.DataFrame(clusters)
labeleddata = pd.concat((data,labels),axis=1)
labeleddata = labeleddata.rename({0:'labels'},axis=1)
```

I am not sure why it assumes there is only one sample as my dataset has 4414 rows. Please help!

Comment: Can you verify that `data_norm_df` contains all 4414 rows and not just one?

Comment: @mikulatomas yup, it does. i verified that